# Problema al relacionar 3 entidades en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, datatables, mysql-workbench

Tengo 3 tablas: **USUARIO**, **ROL** y **GRUPO**.
Los roles sólo son otorgados a aquellos usuarios que pertenezcan a un grupo, vale decir que un usuario no tiene un rol en si mismo a menos que pertenezca a un grupo. Cada usuario puede tener un rol distinto dependiendo de cada grupo, haciendo válida la siguiente expresión:

- Usuario A pertenece a Grupo A con Rol A
- Usuario A pertenece a Grupo B con Rol A
- Usuario A pertenece a Grupo C con Rol B

Relaciones

**Un usuario** puede pertenecer a **muchos grupos**

**Un usuario** puede tener **muchos roles**

**Un grupo** puede contener a **muchos usuarios (con roles)**

**Un rol** puede pertenecer a **muchos usuarios (con grupo)**

Un modelado sencillo sería de la siguiente forma:

[image: Modelo Base de Datos]

No es recomendable que las tablas pivotes tengan más de dos tablas relacionadas. Quisiera saber ¿cómo sería la forma correcta de relacionar estas 3 tablas?

Answer (score 0):

Te veo debatiéndote entres estos tres posibles modelos:

a) El que has implementado:

[image: Abstracción]

b) El que no te atreves a implementar por algo que te han contado sobre tablas pivote, que no he entendido muy bien, pero que me suena una relación de grado 3:

[image: Grado 3]

c) El que soluciona tu problema:

[image: Dos relaciones de grado 2]

Todos y cada uno tienen ventajas e inconvenientes, al final el bueno será el que mejor solucione el problema que quieres modelar.

a) En esta solución decides qué roles concedes a cada uno de los usuarios en función del grupo al que pertenece. El matiz es que decides con cada uno, no hay un criterio preestablecido a no ser que lo implementes en la aplicación que explote esa base de datos. Problema: que puedes tener un usuario en un grupo y se olvide asignarle un rol. Por los ejemplos de tu pregunta podría encajar, pero la frase "Cada usuario puede tener un rol distinto dependiendo de cada grupo" lo contradice.

b) Aquí decides, en el momento de incluir a un usuario en un grupo, qué rol quieres asignarle. Tienes la misma arbitrariedad que en el caso a), pero aquí no te dejarás a nadie sin rol, a no ser que admitas nulos en esa relación de grado 3.

c) Con este modelo ya tienes predefinidos los roles asignados a cada grupo de usuarios. De forma que, con incluir a un usuario en un grupo, ya "hereda" de forma automática todos los roles que tenga ese grupo.

Casi lo tenías :)

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y le damos las vueltas que quieras.